# Application apex_item_checkbox in apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have used a checkbox in intractive report, now i have a delete button also here.

i need to delete the records which user checked on checkbox.

my select query in intractive report is below.

```
select distinct
    a.GUID,
    a.CREATED_BY,
    a.created_date,
    apex_item.checkbox(1,b.DYNAMIC_GROUP_ID) Delete_Members
from NON_DYNAMIC_USER_GROUP_MEMBERS a,
    NON_DYNAMIC_USER_GROUPS b
where a.DYNAMIC_GROUP_ID in
    (select DYNAMIC_GROUP_ID
    from NON_DYNAMIC_USER_GROUPS
    where instr(','||DYNAMIC_GROUP_ID||',' , ','||:P153_ID_HIDDEN||',') > 0);
```

I need here to delete the records where the check box is checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created video some times ago which covers your problem. It's step by step tutorial how to create and process rows with checkboxes.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-LXRMWQbPk&feature=youtu.be

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a process to loop through the array which contains the checkbox ID's and then implement your delete logic.

```
FOR i IN 1..apex_application.g_f01.count -- g_f01 as you used id 1 on your checkbox
LOOP
    <<delete logic here>>
    WHERE <id_of_table_to_delete> = i.dynamic_group_id
END LOOP;
```